# How to validate a Map snippet in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have an dynamic html file that groovy is generated from.  Part of this html template format is `{routeId}{groovyMap}` like so

```
 USER_FORM[name:'Dean', user:randomFunction([item:'s', day:'Tuesday'])]
```

or something like

```
 USER_FORM[name: 'Dean', user: user]
```

I made the first example more complex.  Currently, I split on ':' and validate all the keys supplied.  What I would like to do is take the groovy snippet and grab all the keys and validate

```
 1. all keys are strings
 2. validate the keys against some meta data I already have
```

I do not care about the values at all.  Currently, I split on ':' but obviously that won't work for all cases.  I am worried about other complex cases I may not be thinking about.

This is for a templating engine and I prefer to failfast if possible making it easier on the user when something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with others that you want to avoid parsing directly.

If you use `GroovyShell`, you can dope the input string with no-op `methodMissing` and `propertyMissing` handlers. In this way, even the complex example will work.

See code below, including test-cases (extracting map string from the "USER_FORMstr" format is left to the reader).

```
class KeyGenerator {
    // these could be "final static". omitted for brevity
    def shell = new GroovyShell() 
    def methodMissingHandler = "def methodMissing(String name, args) {}"
    def propertyMissingHandler = "def propertyMissing(String name) {}"

    def generateKeys(mapStr) {
        def evalInput = "${methodMissingHandler} ; " +
                        "${propertyMissingHandler} ; " + 
                        "${mapStr}"
        def map = shell.evaluate(evalInput)
        return map.keySet()
    }
}

// ------- main

def keyGenerator = new KeyGenerator()
def expected = new HashSet()
expected << "name"
expected << "user"

def mapStr = "[name:'Dean', user:randomFunction([item:'s', day:'Tuesday'])]"
assert expected == keyGenerator.generateKeys(mapStr)

def mapStr2 = "[name: 'Dean', user: user]"
assert expected == keyGenerator.generateKeys(mapStr2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you can use something like:

```
String val = "USER_FORM[name:'Dean', user:randomFunction([item:'s', day:'Tuesday'])]"
def res = []
val.eachMatch( /[\[,] ?(\w+):/ ){ res << it[ 1 ] }
assert '[name, user, item, day]' == res.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. all keys are strings

When using the literal syntax for creating a `Map`, i.e.

```
Map m = [foo: 'bar']
```

as opposed to

```
Map m = new HashMap()
m.put('foo', 'bar')
```

the keys are *always* strings, even if you have a variable in scope with the same name as the key. For example, in the following snippet, the key will be the string `'foo'`, not the integer `6`

```
def foo = 6
Map m = [foo: 'bar']
```

The only way you can create a `Map` using the literal syntax with a key that is *not* a string is if you have a variable in scope with the same name as the key *and* you wrap the key name in parentheses. For example, in the following snippet, the key will be the integer `6`, not the string `'foo'`

```
def foo = 6
Map m = [(foo): 'bar']
```

> Currently, I split on ':' but obviously that won't work for all cases. I am worried about other complex cases I may not be thinking about.

Parsing a map literal using regex/string splitting seems like a bad idea as you'll likely end up badly re-implementing the Groovy lexer. Something like the following seems a better option

```
def mapString = '[foo: "bar"]'    
Map map = Eval.me(mapString)

// now you can process the map via the Map interface, e.g.
map.keySet().toList() == ['foo']
```